# Assign value to next value controller

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

i want to pass data to next view controller but i don't want to move to that view controller. i want to move to another view controller. 
here is my testing code Home View Controller is the class which i want to send data. and i want to move to another view controller which is moving through segue. this method give me null value to homeviewcontroller

```
    if email.text == em && pwd.text == pw
    {

        let des = HomeViewController()
        des.ema = em
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: nil)            
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Answer (score 0):

Add on prepareforSegue method :

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "segue" {
        let destination = segue.destination as! HomeViewController
        destination.ema = em
    }
}
```

Or if you want an "other" View Controller

```
 let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier :"HomeViewController")
 viewController.ema = em
 self.present(viewController, animated: true)
```

Comment: i know this method. but i want to move another view controller and pass the value to another view controller

Comment: Ok I changed my answer :)